# Webview does not show anything

Tags: android, android-layout, android-webview

I want to use a WebView. Here is my code:

```
    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/webview"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:visibility="gone"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.75"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

---

```
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.webkit.WebView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        String url = "wwww.google.com";
        WebView view = (WebView)this.findViewById(R.id.webview);
        view.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        view.loadUrl(url);

    }
}
```

Where is my mistake ?

Comment: Why there is 4 w in URL `wwww`? also there is no prefix `http://` or `https:/`. Remove `android:visibility="gone"`from xml.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make the complete URL: http://www.google.com or https://www.google.com

As the snippet of code shows, the visibility is also set to GONE so it won't appear in the screen.